# MySQL search multiple tables with different column names

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to live search two tables in MySQL. I have the following query using UNION. When I get the result back, the keys are always from the first table columns only; [username], [pfp], [pro_bg_color]. How do I get the different table keys from the two different tables so I can sort through the data?

QUERY:

```
$query = "(SELECT `username`, `pfp`, `pro_bg_color`, 'user' AS `type` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%{$ok['search_for']}%' AND account_status = 'active') ";
$query .= " UNION ";
$query .= "(SELECT `cluster_id`, `pp_pfp`, `pp_name`, 'page' AS `type` FROM `pixelpage` WHERE `pp_name` LIKE '%{$ok['search_for']}%')";
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [username] => demo
        [pfp] => 43867771.jpg
        [pro_bg_color] => 9ddd13
        [type] => user
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [username] => jimmy
        [pfp] => 43867770.jpg
        [pro_bg_color] => 2a00ff
        [type] => user
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [username] => 1004
        [pfp] => 2201fc2d.jpg
        [pro_bg_color] => My Page Title
        [type] => page
    )
```

)

Comment: UNION vs UNION ALL Learn the different between union and union all SQL statement and their performance.
 
UNION
 
The UNION command is used to select related information from two tables, which is like a JOIN command. However, when using UNION command, all the selected columns need to be of the same data type. With UNION, only distinct values are selected.
 
UNION ALL
 
UNION ALL command is equal to UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all the values.

Example

Table 1 : First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth
Table 2 : First,Second,Fifth,Sixth

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out as follows:

```
$query = "(SELECT `user_id` AS `id`, `username` AS `name`, `pfp` AS `pic`, `pro_bg_color` AS `bg_color`,  'user' AS `type` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%{$ok['search_for']}%' AND account_status = 'active') ";
$query .= " UNION ";
$query .= "(SELECT `cluster_id` AS `id`, `pp_name` AS `name`, `pp_pfp` AS `pic`, `pp_banner` AS `bg_color`, 'page' AS `type` FROM `pixelpage` WHERE `pp_name` LIKE '%{$ok['search_for']}%')";
```